# How to reset openfire data?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

In a long-running openfire server. Is there a way to clear the data currently exists and reset configurations to defaults?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your openfire directory, if you edit the `conf/openfire.xml` file and change the value in the `<setup>` tags (usually at the bottom of the page), from `true` to `false`, it will force you to go through the installation process again. Good for resetting your admin password if you forgot it.

If you want to get rid of the plugins loaded, remove things from the `plugin` directory.

If you want to get rid of data (and you're using a database), drop and recreate said database and redo the permissions for Openfire.

Alternatively, (if you installed via `RPM`), you could uninstall (`rpm -e openfire`) and install again.